# Is There Any Point in Using Synonymous Tags (like i and dfn)

Tags: html

Is there any additional effect behind the scenes in using something like dfn, instead of i? Is there any browser that actually implements a special use for something like dfn, such as a special type of find menu that finds the definition for terms?

Comment: `dfn` is used for different things semantically. Looks the same but is semantically different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp):

> Use the <i> element only when there is not a more appropriate semantic
>   element, such as:
>
> - <em> (emphasized text)
> - <strong> (important text)
> - <mark> (marked/highlighted text)
> - <cite> (the title of a work)
> - <dfn> (a definition term)

I don't have any specific example, as I've never used the settings myself, but one of the reasons the HTML specification focuses on *semantic meaning* (such as `<dfn>`) as opposed to general modifiers (such as `<i>`) is that it's intended to be usable my handicapped people. For instance, if you use `<dfn>` and `<em>` instead of just using `<i>` everywhere, a screen reader reading a page to a blind person will be able to produce better and more intelligent output.